# Removing elements by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with the following structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|1</td>
    <td id="abc|1">abc</td>
    <td id="abc|1">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|1</td>
    <td id="def|1">def</td>
    <td id="def|1">def</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ome column|2</td>
    <td id="abc|2">abc</td>
    <td id="abc|2">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|2</td>
    <td id="def|2">def</td>
    <td id="def|2">def</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The content comes from a database.

As you can see, the IDs have the suffix `|x`. I want to remove all elements with the suffix `|2` in the 2nd column and all elements with the suffix `|1` in the 3rd column.
Also the 3rd column should be shifted to the top, and all rows ending with `|2` in the 1st column should disappear.

So that the final result looks like that:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|1</td>
    <td id="abc|1">abc</td>
    <td id="abc|2">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|1</td>
    <td id="def|1">def</td>
    <td id="def|2">def</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is my approach, but it doesn't work at all:

```
$("table td:nth-child(2)").find("[id$=2]").each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

$("table td:nth-child(3)").find("[id$=1]").each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsmtstxo/6/).

Comment: What about the cell at the start of each row, with elements removed and which has no `id`, and is not present in your final result? If the first cell is the only cell should it also be removed?

Comment: I know that you're using placeholder `id` attributes in your question, but be aware that all `id` atributes within a page must be unique.

Comment: First of all Id should be uniq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ID should be unique.** It's better if you can change the HTML and make IDs unique.

---

**IF CHANGING HTML IS NOT POSSIBLE**

As both the selector are pointing to same element, use following

```
$("table td:nth-child(2)[id$=2], table td:nth-child(3)[id$=1]").hide();
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/bsmtstxo/8/)

Comment: Please mind, that there should be 3 columns as the final result, as provided in my example.

Comment: The content of the 3rd column should remain there and to be shifted to the left into the 2nd column.